# mysql_pconnect() - Nginx, php5-fpm, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, nginx

I have a game, which is divided in 3 worlds. Today i made update in world 3 in my game.

After update mysql_pconnect changing a selected database randomly, though i have set database 's3'. Few seconds on my site i see data from database 's2' or 's1'.

I create a new user for my database 's3' and when i connecting everything is ok, but mysql create new threads for one user connection, so what can be problem?

On ever world I use same user for mysql_pconnect, so i should make a user for every database?

```
class MySQL {

static public function ConnectToDb($Host, $User, $Password, $Database) {

    @mysql_pconnect($Host, $User, $Password) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($Database);
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');

}

$System['BazaDanych'] = array('login' => 'root', 'haslo' => '', 'host' => 'localhost', 'baza' => 's2');

MySQL::ConnectToDb($KonfiguracjaSystemu['BazaDanych']['host'] , $KonfiguracjaSystemu['BazaDanych']['login'] , $KonfiguracjaSystemu['BazaDanych']['haslo'] , $KonfiguracjaSystemu['BazaDanych']['baza']);
```

It is code from my local config.

TOm

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Additionally, writing a wrapper around this ancient interface is a complete waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

First, when connecting, the function would first try to find a (persistent) link that's already open with the same host, username and password. If one is found, an identifier for it will be returned instead of opening a new connection.

Second, the connection to the SQL server will not be closed when the execution of the script ends. Instead, the link will remain open for future use (mysql_close() will not close links established by mysql_pconnect()).

Read more about this in:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php

Comment: but i can't understand, why mysql create more threads than people whom is online

Comment: try to close your connections with mysql_close();

Comment: Yesterday i changed mysql_pconnect on mysql_connect, and on every page i have mysql_close(), now is ok. I decided to mysql_pconnect, because i have a lot of ajax intervals. I must stay with mysql_connect - thanks.